# Crash Analysis Foundation _NSErrnoMessage

Tags: ios

[image]

Crash log analysis, which encountered a similar problem, help look at, thank you.

Comment: as a beginner please explain your question as much as possible. By the way add a break point exception in your code as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: I would suggest read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Im experiencing the same crash, but cannot understand where it's coming from. Have you fixed this, or found the cause?